# Write pre-determined node id when pushing to Firebase array

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This question has been asked before, but none of the solutions provided seem to help my problem:

I have an array of data on Firebase, that I loop through to generate content in my app, using a "for" loop and therefore an index value. This works fine with the predetermined sets of data, as the IDs are simple array numerics but when a user adds some new data, which is added to the array with push(), firebase creates a unique node key (such as -KyWRU7RRCE_V1w_OiZx) for the new set of data which for some reason prevents my loop from working (no errors shown in console).

If I go to firebase and manually ensure that the new set of data has a numeric value, loop starts working again. How do I make it so that when the user pushes new data to the array, the key being generated is numeric? I tried this:

```
  // Push new routine to Firebase.
  var firebaseRef = firebase.database().ref();
  var createdExercise = JSON.parse(localStorage.newRoutine);
  $("#save").click(function()
  {
    firebaseRef.child("workouts").key(some_indexed_value).push(createdExercise);
  });
```

but the console returns the following error: Uncaught TypeError: firebaseRef.child(...).key is not a function.

In case it is useful, here is the loop I am using:

```
// Initialize Firebase.
firebase.initializeApp(config);
// Reference data.
var dbRef = firebase.database().ref().child("workouts");
// Sync with Firebase in real time.
dbRef.on("value", snap =>
{
  var workouts = snap.val();

  for (var i = 0; i < workouts.length; i++)
  {
    var routine = workouts[i].title;
    var time = 3;
    var exercises = workouts[i].exercises;
    var icons;

    $("#cardList").append(createCards(routine));
  }
});
```

And a pic of my JSON data on Firebase: [image: Firebase JSON tree]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer to your question is using `.set()` instead of `.push()` like this

```
firebaseRef.child("workouts").child(some_indexed_value).set(createdExercise);
```

this will create a node under workouts with your custom key.

but it is recommended to use `push keys` and use `forEach()` method to get the result than using `for loop`

Comment: SUPER! Thank you so much.